# Controlador devuelve list con datos pero en la vista no se muestra (Spring)

Tags: java, spring

Soy nueva en esto de Spring, he realizado una aplicación todo funciona bien, excepto que aunque la lista en el controlador se mapea llena, no muestra los valores en el jsp.

```
@Controller
public class DBUserController {

    @Autowired
    private DBUserService dbuserService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String listDBUser(Map<String, Object> map) {

        map.put("DBUserList", dbuserService.listDBUser());

        return "DBUser";
    }

}

 <c:forEach items="${DBUserList}" var="DBUser">
    <tr>
        <td>${DBUser.username}</td>
        <td>${DBUser.createdBy}</td>
    </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Para que es la variable `map`?. Que hace el método (que retorna?)`dbuserService.listDBUser()`?

Comment: la variable map es para que la vista pueda acceder a la lista y dbuserService.listDBUser() devuelve un listado que previamente ya valide si retorna datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada recuerda poner esto en la seccion `head` te tu jsp:

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>`

y anadir como dependencia [`https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2).

Luego hay varias opciones.

*Opcion 1*:

En `public String listDBUser(Map<String, Object> map)` no recibas como argumento un objeto de tipo `Map<String, Object>`, sino [`ModelMap`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html) o [`Model`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html).

```
@Controller
public class DBUserController {

    @Autowired
    private DBUserService dbuserService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String listDBUser(ModelMap map) {  // <-- recibir argumento de tipo ModelMap

        map.addAttribute("DBUserList", dbuserService.listDBUser()); // <-- adicionar la lista en el atributo DBUserList

        return "DBUser";  // <-- suponinendo que "DBUser" es el nombre de tu vista
    }

}
```

*Opcion 2*:

1. No retornes `String` del método `listDBUser`, sino [`ModelAndView`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html)
2. No es necesario que envies un `Map` como parámetro al método `listDBUser` (servicio en url `/`).

---

**controlador**

```
@Controller
public class DBUserController {

    @Autowired
    private DBUserService dbuserService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView listDBUser() {  // <-- quitar argumento aqui y cambiar retorno a ModelAndView

        // crear objeto ModelAndView para retornar
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("DBUser"); // <-- suponinendo que "DBUser" es el nombre de tu vista
        modelAndView.addObject("DBUserList", dbuserService.listDBUser());

        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

---

Este excelente [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-model-map-model-view) explica estos conceptos.

Comment: Hola, la primera opción ya la había probado, acabo de probar la segunda opción y no me ha funcionado =(

Comment: @MargieGiselleOrellanoCassia has comprobado si hay algún error en los logs? También chequea que tengas las dependencias instaladas correctamente. Dejame saber como vas.

Comment: @MargieGiselleOrellanoCassia pudieras probar tambien poner esto en la seccion `head` te tu jsp: `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>` y anadir como dependencia `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl/1.2` ? Hay un post similar en StackOverflow en ingles donde fue necesario anadir esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42054829/display-list-of-values-on-jsp-using-spring

Comment: Muchas gracias =) era eso, de verdad tienes toda mi gratitud.

Comment: Que bueno que te ayudó. Edité la respuesta para añadir esta información relevante. Recuerda [**marcarla como aceptada**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para que futuros lectores sepan que te ayudó a resolver el problema. Cuando tengas (+ [reputacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)) el [privilegio de votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) podras dar votos positivos a posts utiles como este ya que [votar es importante](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) en comunidades como estas.